# Can I still use the react-particles-js?

Tags: javascript, npm

I just saw that this package has been deprecated here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js

I just want to know if I can still use this?

These are the codes: https://codesandbox.io/s/particle-js-background-forked-woypk?file=/src/Particles.js:65-83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know if I can still use this?

Yes, so long as it's not removed from npm registry. You can always fork it so you've a copy. Deprecation just means it is no longer being actively maintained.

You may want to move to [tsParticles](https://particles.js.org/) and specifically [react-tsparticles](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/tree/main/components/react) though, as that `react-particles-js` repo suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated packages can still be used, and npm generally will never remove a released version of a package unless it contains a security vulnerability. However, the package being deprecated means the developer will not be updating it, and they strongly recommend using another package.